# Between two dates

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I can't figure out why the findOne function doesn't work. My code

```
  async getSign(childrenId: number, week?: number, year?: number) {
    if (week && year) {
      const startDate = moment().year(year).week(week).startOf("week").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const endDate = moment().year(year).week(week).endOf("week").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log(startDate, endDate);
      const signature = await this.diarySignRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          childrenId,
          date: {
            $between: [startDate, endDate]
          }
        },
        attributes: ['sign'],
      });
      return signature?.sign;
    }
  }
```

My request:

```
http://localhost:5000/diary/sign/get/1?week=11&year=2023
```

In database i have record:

```
|id |childrenId|date      |sign|
|---|----------|----------|----|
|2  |1         |2023-03-17|true|
```

In console i get:

```
2023-03-12 2023-03-18
Executing (default): SELECT "sign" FROM "diary_sign" AS "DiarySign" WHERE "DiarySign"."childrenId" = '1' AND "DiarySign"."date" = '2023-02-18' LIMIT 1;
```

I don't understand why between doesn't work

**Edit:**
I used Javascript functions (**not SQL**) to get the result, because I don't understand what could be the reason for this behavior:

```
 async getStatusDiarySign(childrenId: number, week?: number, year?: number) {
    if (week && year) {
      const startDate = moment()
        .year(year)
        .week(week)
        .startOf("week")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const endDate = moment()
        .year(year)
        .week(week)
        .endOf("week")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log(startDate, endDate);
      const diarySigns = await this.diarySignRepository.findAll({
        where: {
          childrenId,
        },
      });
      let sign = false;
      diarySigns.some((diarySign) => {
        const date = moment(diarySign.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
          sign = diarySign.sign;
          return sign;
        }
      });
      return sign;
    }
```

Comment: What version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: @Emma sequelize version is 6.28

Comment: okay. Try changing the `$between` to `[Op.between]` (`const { Op } = require("sequelize")`). `$between` is deprecated since v5.   https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is incorrect:

```
SELECT "sign" FROM "diary_sign" AS "DiarySign" 
WHERE "DiarySign"."childrenId" = '1' 
AND "DiarySign"."date" = '2023-02-18' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Your database has `2023-03-17` whilst you're searching for `2023-02-18`.

As a sanity check, remove `date: { $between: [startDate, endDate] }`, your SQL query will then search over `childrenId`, returning the expected entry.

To search dates correctly, `startDate` and `endDate` must be `Date` objects, whereas you're using strings, fix that. (Apply `.format("YYYY-MM-DD")` in `console.log` for pretty printing.) If that doesn't work, we'll need to see `diarySignRepository.findOne`.

Comment: That is the problem. I want to return a value that falls between startDate and endDate, but $between is ignored and date is compared to today's date

Comment: Code isn't being ignored *per se*, it's generating `"DiarySign"."date" = '2023-02-18'`

Comment: Updated. The problem might be in `diarySignRepository.findOne`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the date field is a string while the comparison operator $between is for dates. You need to cast the start date and end date to date first by using the following code:

`new Date(startDate).`

The reason why you can retrieve the value for signature field is because signature is a boolean type.

So the updated expression will be: `$between:[new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)]`.